# How can I download/open linearized PDF string with JS

Tags: javascript, pdf, download, frontend

I'm retrieving a PDF file from a file storage service. When it comes back it looks like this...

```
%PDF-1.6
%����
131 0 obj
<</Linearized 1/L 88418/O 133/E 80203/N 1/T 88084/H [ 633 263]>>
endobj etc etc etc...
```

From here, I need to open the file in browser, so I create a blob object and trigger it's download.

```
  const blob = new Blob([response.data], { type: "application/pdf" });

  const aTag = document.createElement("a");
  aTag.setAttribute("download", "test");
  const href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  aTag.href = href;
  aTag.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
  aTag.click();

  URL.revokeObjectURL(href);
```

This does indeed prompt a download, but it's blank with an error.

Where am I loosing the data? What am I missing?

I asked ChatGPT and it had me looking at ArrayBuffers and Uint8Arrays. Below I'll insert the code it recommended, which I used. When I run the below, I get the same error.

Any help or guidance will be appreciated. I don't know what I don't know here.

```
  const arrayBuffer = new ArrayBuffer(response.data.length);
  const uint8Array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
  for (let i = 0; i < response.data.length; i++) {
    uint8Array[i] = response.data.charCodeAt(i);
  }

  const blob = new Blob([uint8Array], { type: "application/pdf" });

  const aTag = document.createElement("a");
  aTag.setAttribute("download", "test");
  const href = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
  aTag.href = href;
  aTag.setAttribute("target", "_blank");
  aTag.click();

  URL.revokeObjectURL(href);
```

Comment: Indeed, the `%����` line looks like the pdf file has been treated as a text file somewhere, as a file with a specific global character encoding. Doing so damaged pdfs usually. I don't know Javascript details but already `charCodeAt` has the air of applying a character encoding.